# Как логировать ошибки даже при их отлавливании?

Tags: php, исключения

Предположим, что у нас выбрасывается какое-то исключение. Если мы его **не отлавливаем** `try/catch/final`, то оно и все данные (в зависимости от обработчика) пишутся в логи. Это хорошее и нужное поведение. Если мы то же самое исключение **будет отлавливать**, то никуда ничего не попадет (про записи в логи).

Вопрос: как автоматически писать в логи исключения, даже при их отлове?

Comment: расширить класс исключений, добавив в него логирование

Comment: @splash58 да, можно, но надо подумать как связать с фреймворком (чтобы работал аналогично)

Comment: пользуйтесь его логгером

Comment: @splash58 попробую сейчас